# GCM message is getting overridden

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am using GCM push notification to pass some notification to the user. My problem is when am sending single message then this works fine if send more than one then the last message is shown to all the notification.

Where have I made a mistake?

```
  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
          context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, GCMMessageView.class);
  String[] messageArray = message.split("\\#");
  // param :: agentId, Name, Msg
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
  int notificationId = db.insertnotifications(messageArray[1], messageArray[0], messageArray[messageArray.length-1]);

  notificationIntent.putExtra("message", messageArray[messageArray.length-1]);
  // set intent so it does not start a new activity
  notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

  Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentText(messageArray[messageArray.length-1])
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setWhen(when)
        .setContentIntent(intent)
        .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make notification id unique for each message. Due to this, it's being overridden.

Comment: How to do it using HTTP Request ? Have any idea ?

Answer (score 9):

used this coding in your notification

```
  int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID,
  notificationIntent,0 );
```

then your notification will not override i hope this will help u

Comment: Not sure what I missed but even after adding current time as you mentioned was not working as expected. I updated the notification id in notify method which resolved the issue, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes agree with Dipo's answer. According to [Android Notification Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) This is being overridden due to same notification id for more than one notification.SO the last message is being received on receiver end. You need to Implement random unique Notification id for each notifications. There are number of ways to implement this . You can use this

```
int notificationId = new Random().nextInt();
```

You can also use system time in Mili Seconds for Notification id.Then you need to pass this unique Notification ID to `notificationManager.notify()`

Cheers ! Keep Coding

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to answer for the thread but felt it will be helpful for someone. The same implementation works fine for FCM firebase implementation as well

```
// Get a random value 
int notificationId = new Random().nextInt();
// Add the notification ID which is unique as a first value of the notify method.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```