# Push notification overrides previous notifications

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using [codeigniter-gcm](https://github.com/antongorodezkiy/codeigniter-gcm) library on top of codeigniter to send messages to Google Cloud Messaging service. It sends the message and the message is received at the mobile device, but if I send multiple messages, only the latest message appears on the device (as if it is overriding the previous messages).

I'm seeing that I might need to create a unique notification ID, but I'm not seeing how it's done anywhere on the codeigniter-gcm documentation or Google's documentation for downstream messages.

Any idea how this should be done?

Here's my code in the codeigniter controller. It is worth mentioning that Google's response contains a different message_id for each time I send a push...

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library("gcm");
    $this->gcm->setMessage("Test message sent on " . date("d.m.Y H:i:s"));
    $this->gcm->addRecepient("*****************");
    $this->gcm->setData(array(
        'title' => 'my title',
        'some_key' => 'some_val'
    ));
    $this->gcm->setTtl(false);
    $this->gcm->setGroup(false);
    if ($this->gcm->send())
        echo 'Success for all messages';
    else
        echo 'Some messages have errors';

    print_r($this->gcm->status);
    print_r($this->gcm->messagesStatuses);
}
```

Comment: there's no issue in php code. but its from android as far as i know. in android there's one integer parameter when generating notification. that parameter should be different all time when you have to generate new notificaiton

Comment: Hi Aiyaz, thanks for the answer. I suspected that I needed to generate a unique value somewhere but I can't figure out where and couldn't find any reference on Google's documentation. Any idea what's the parameter name I have to add to the JSON object?

Comment: hey yosi just check this out `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856409/gcm-message-is-getting-overridden/20856525#20856525`

Comment: Hi Aiyaz. I ran into this answer couple days and that made me believe I had to add the notification id, but couldn't find it anywhere on GCM docs. Now that you pointed out at this answer again, I decided to poke down the Java code and figure out what it dos to the JSON object. I'll post the solution as a separate answer in hope it may help other people...

Answer (score 3):

After three exhausting days I found the solution. I'm posting it here in hope of saving someone else's time...

I had to add a parameter to the data object inside the greater JSON object, named "notId" with a unique integer value (which I chose to use a random integer from a wide range). Now why Google didn't include this in their docs? Beats me...

Here's how my JSON looks now, when it creates separate notifications instead of overriding:

```
{
    "data": {
                "some_key":"some_val",
                "title":"test title",
                "message":"Test message from 30.09.2015 12:57:44",
                "notId":14243
            },
    "registration_ids":["*******"]
}
```

- Edit:
  I'm now thinking that the notId parameter is not really determined by Google, but by a plugin I use on the mobile app side.
  To extend further on my environment, my mobile app is developed using Phonegap, so to get push notification I use [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) which I now see in its docs that parameter name.
  I'm kinda' lost now as far as explaining the situation - but happy it is no longer a problem for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a unique ID to each notification. Once you have clicked on the notification you use that ID to remove it.

```
    ...
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_A);
...
```

But I'm sure you shouldn't have so much of notifications for user at once. You should show a single notification that consolidates info about group of events like for example Gmail client does. Use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) for that purpose.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c);
   b.setNumber(g_push.Counter)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.list_avatar))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_example)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle(pushCount > 1 ? c.getString(R.string.stat_messages_title) + pushCount : title)
    .setContentText(pushCount > 1 ? push.ProfileID : mess)
    .setWhen(g_push.Timestamp)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, it, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
    .setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(ACTION_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    .setSound(Uri.parse(prefs.getString(
            SharedPreferencesID.PREFERENCE_ID_PUSH_SOUND_URI,
            "android.resource://ru.mail.mailapp/raw/new_message_bells")));
```

Comment: 1. I might need to send 2-3 different types of notification at a short period of time, so I don't necessarily want to group them together.
2. How do I set the unique ID in the JSON object that I send to GCM? What is the parameter name?

3. I'm actually writing my server-side code in PHP, so the Notification.Builder won't work for me. Do you know of any PHP equivalent?

Comment: Ok, But still if your problem is the notification ovveride it's because of the ID. You Just need to change it every time

Comment: That's exactly what I'm try to figure out how to do... Thanks anyway, Giacomo!

Comment: How did you developed your current notification method? Tomorrow I will post an example, But I would like to see how you did it

Comment: I'm developing my server-side on a PHP framework, called CodeIgniter. It allows plugins and I found a plugin that sends the notification (all I have to do is instantiate an object and use some setter methods to provide the details of the notification). Essentially, I think I might have to modify the plugin (which I have no problem doing so), so all I need to know is the syntax/structure of the expected JSON object. I couldn't find on Google's documentation any reference to a notification id...