# How to display each push notification separately on android device using GCM

Tags: php, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification to my phonegap app from server. Its getting delivered successfully, but the problem is if I send multiple notifications old one get overrides.
For example 
at 10:00 AM - 
Notification 1 Received 
at 10:01 AM
Notification 2 Received
in this Notification 1 Received get overwrite by second message. But I want to show both messages as they important.
I googled it and found solution on stackoverflow for same.

[GCM message is getting overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856409/gcm-message-is-getting-overridden)

but its for android, and I am using phonegap and php to send notification,
is there any way to assign that we can retain both messages on user screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Cordova plugin are you using to show notifications?

Comment: I am using this plugin : https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git, but it is just to register device with gcm, to send push notification I am using PHP at server side

Comment: Did the solution below work for you? If it did, you really should accept the answer as correct as it will help others with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the payload data you are sending with PHP.

From the documentation at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

> **tag:**  Indicates whether each notification message results in a new entry on the notification center on Android. If not set, each request creates a new notification. If set, and a notification with the same tag is already being shown, the new notification replaces the existing one in notification center.

One option is to treat tag as a *uniqid*, as long as you do not really need to go back and update some unread notifications. If you do need to update a notification, choose an id that works in your case.